# SFML Internal OpenAL error

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I have myself a SoundLoader class which loads some wav files into a map of soundbuffers and then I can call a method called PlaySound which takes an enum to play the sound, here is my method

```
void SoundLoader::PlaySound(SoundNames soundName)
{

if (playingSounds.size() == 0)
{
    playingSounds.push_back(sf::Sound());
    playingSounds.at(0).setBuffer(Sounds[soundName]);
    playingSounds.at(0).play();
}
else
{
    int location = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < playingSounds.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!playingSounds.at(i).getStatus() == sf::Sound::Playing && location != -1)
        {
            location = i;
        }
    }

    if (location != -1)
    {
        playingSounds.at(location).setBuffer(Sounds[soundName]);
        playingSounds.at(location).play();
    }
    else
    {
        playingSounds.push_back(sf::Sound());
        playingSounds.at(playingSounds.size()-1).setBuffer(Sounds[soundName]);
        playingSounds.at(playingSounds.size() - 1).play();
    }

}
}
```

However I was testing my game and for a minute or so it is all going fine, but then all of a sudden I got this error

```
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundSource.cpp (181) : AL_INVALID_NAME, an unacceptable name has been specified
```

What am I doing to cause this? P.S. my soundloader only has 60 lines of code so not sure what the 181 is relating to

Answer (score 1):

Its ok I found out my error

```
if (playingSounds.at(i).getStatus() != sf::Sound::Playing && location == -1)
        {
            location = i;
        }
```

Just to help any other person that has this problem, make sure you never have more than 140 sf::Sounds in memory or this will break. this was breaking for me when my playingSounds.size() was equal to 140